# How to replace jest.spyOn().and.returnValue()?

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine, nrwl

While upgrading Angular (via Nx/NRWL) from 11 to 12, tests started to fail due to: `Property 'and' does not exist on type 'SpyInstance<{ afterClosed: () => Observable<{ snoozeDate: Moment; snoozeNote: string; }>; }, []>'.`

There are ~30 some tests that use the .and.returnValue.

Examples:

- `jest.spyOn(mockMatDialog, 'open').and.returnValue({ afterClosed: () => of(true)});`,
- `jest.spyOn(component.randomHelperService, 'myHelper').and.returnValue('12354');`

What is the best way to replace this "returnValue" behavior? FYI, I have this set too, `testRunner: 'jest-jasmine2',` in order to make other syntax work after the upgrade.

Answer (score 15):

You can change the `testRunner` back and use `mockReturnValue` instead of `and.returnValue`. [See](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue)

```typescript
jest.spyOn(mockMatDialog, 'open').mockReturnValue({ afterClosed: () => of(true)});
jest.spyOn(component.randomHelperService, 'myHelper').mockReturnValue('12354');
```

I'm not sure when it was changed but I had to deal with the same issue. This was the solution